# Short story from the 1990s about a transgender Native American in the 1800s

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, sexuality

I've been searching for a short story I read, I believe in the early 1990s, where the main character was a Native American (possibly female) with a transgender female friend from the same tribe, and at one point they are going off to fight another tribe, and the friend changes into male clothes so if killed, she won't be stripped and mocked as a coward for having dressed as a woman. They also have friendly relations with a number of Europeans (trappers? military?) who I believe didn't have a permanent station in the area. One of the male Europeans goes off with the friend down to the river and when he comes back some of his friends prod him about what happened, to which he says something like "well, I found out we had a lot in common." They may have been Lakota and the other side Crow, or vice versa; it was definitely set in the Great Plains, in the 19th century; there's no mention of reservations, so probably before 1876.

I strongly suspect it came out of one of the magazines I was reading at the time, *Boy's Life*, *Dragon Magazine*, *Isaac Asimov's* or *Fantasy and Science Fiction*. It doesn't seem like a great fit for any of them, so it might have come from an anthology read at the time. (If I have the time period wrong, I added *Ellery Queen* and *Alfred Hitchcock* to my reading by mid to late 1990s.)

Comment: Scouring Google, it's looking likely that it's a short story by [Craig Womack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_Womack) (such as "Dancing Around the Fire", "Speaking into the Dawn", or "Lucy, Ohlahoma, 1911" all from 1993), or a story from *[Earth Song, Sky Spirit](https://www.amazon.com/Earth-Song-Spirit-Clifford-Trafzer/dp/0385469608)* (1997), but I unfortunately can't find any easily accessable copies of any of them to check (or, indeed, a reliable way to contact Dr. Womack).

Comment: "Earth Song, Sky Spirit" is available form the Internet Archive, just requiring a free registration: https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780385469593